# NoSQL - Query Array to return specific element

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Trying to figure out how to query an array in NoSQL to return a specific element.  I have search previous questions for the topic here.

Here's what I have:

```
db.lessons.find({actor:{$in:["Brad Pitt"]}})
```

Comment: Reformatting question to allow source to be syntax-highlighted.

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman -- sorry no clue what you are talking about.  Not enough details for me to understand "reformatting question?"

Comment: I edited your question to reformat it so that the source would be syntax-highlighted: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45662885/revisions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$elemMatch` to query for array element:

```
db.lessons.find({students:{$elemMatch:"Brad Pitt"}})
```

Comment: Thank you for your time!